# Restify and Backbone conflicting on GET route

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, restify

I'm having difficulty using PushState with backbone and [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/). Most of my routes work fine, but there is a conflict on the GET route for a single model. I've worked around this by having restify only serve those that have an `XMLHttpRequest` header set.

**server.js**

```
var app = restify.createServer();
app.use(restify.bodyParser());

// serve static files
app.get(/^\/public\/(.*)/, public.serveFile);

// Read and handle 'post' model
app.get('/posts/:id', function (req, resp, next) {

    // process backbone requests
    if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
        posts.single(req, resp, next);
    } else {
        index(req, resp, next);
    }

});

// a catch all that gives backbone control
app.get(/.*/, index);
```

**Backbone Router**

```
// pushstate is true
routes: {
    '': 'home',
    'posts/:id': 'show', // issues
    '*other': 'default'
},
```

I could have backbone handle all requests on `/posts/` and then create a seperate `api` route to handle the basic `CRUD` operations, but i'd like to preserve a parity if possible.

My current solution works, but it seems wonky, there a better way to handle this?